# attach google-play-service.apk to android program

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services

for using some feather in android should be install google play service otherwise some error occured like:

> google play service is not installed

is there any way to attach "google play service.apk" to compiled android program and install it with own program?

Comment: No.  The Google Play Services are proprietary licensed software, They may not be distributed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot attach any apk, with your apk. You can upload only 1 apk to app store. However you can use google play service in code by adding its dependency in `gradle.build` file. Almost all new (& old) devices have support for google play services, so there is no need for "attaching apk"

Comment: but google play services is not installed in devices by default! and for use some feather have to install it.

Comment: i think most of device come with google play services installed, but you are also  right some devices may not have it. But you cannot attach apk with another apk